# How to rewrite this function using the pipeline operator

Tags: f#

These are the function definitions.

```
func1: 'a -> unit
func2: 'b -> 'a
func3: string -> 'b list
```

The current function

```
let f =  Seq.iter((fun a -> func1(func2 a)) func3(s)
```

This is as far as I got

```
let f =  func3(s) 
           |> ((fun a -> func2 a 
                         |> func1) 
           |> Seq.iter)
```

I have the feeling it should be possible to loose the lambda and the parens'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do without pipes, simply

```
Seq.iter (func1 << func2) << func3
```

(this is a function with some arguments [same than `func3`] and same output than `Seq.iter`).

You can test it

```
let func1 x = printfn "Number: %d" x

let func2 (a, b) = a + b

let func3 = Seq.map (fun n -> (n, 2 * n))

let f : (seq<_> -> unit) = Seq.iter (func1 << func2) << func3

f [1..5]
```

with output

```
Number: 3
Number: 6
Number: 9
Number: 12
Number: 15

val func1 : x:int -> unit
val func2 : a:int * b:int -> int
val func3 : (seq<int> -> seq<int * int>)
val f : (seq<int> -> unit)
val it : unit = ()
```

:)

Answer (score 4):

You can use function composition operator `>>`:

`func3() |> Seq.iter (func2 >> func1)`

Answer (score 2):

I think the question is, why do you want to use the pipeline operator?

I find your original code quite readable. You should not try to use pipeline operator (or function composition) just for the sake of using them. Now, in your code, the input `s` comes at the end, which is a bit unfortunate (you cannot quite see what is the main input for the code). I would probably rewrite it as (also, `s` is not really a descriptive name):

```
s |> func3 
  |> Seq.iter (fun a -> func1 (func2 a))
```

You can use function composition too - but I do not use it very often, because it does not (always) help with readability. But using it in the argument of `Seq.iter` is probably quite reasonable.

On a completely unrelated note, you could just use `for` loop and write:

```
for a in func3 s do
  func1 (func2 a)
```

I actually find this more readable than any other version of the code here (if F# gives you a language feature for iterating over sequences that does exactly what you need, why not use it?)